# Чем обусловлено обязательное использование указателя this

Tags: c++

В данной программе на основе абстрактного базового класса DataStruct был создан производный класс Queue, который по своей сути является очередью. При подмене функций **getdata** и **putdata** программа не компилировалась и била ошибку "идентификатор не найден" и "необъявленный идентификатор", до момента, пока я не стал явно использовать указатель *this*. С чем это может быть связано?

````
using namespace std;
template<class type1> class DataStruct {
public:
    type1 data;
    DataStruct<type1>* head;
    DataStruct<type1>* tail;
    DataStruct<type1>* next;
    DataStruct() {
        data = NULL; head = tail = next = NULL;
    }
    virtual type1 getdata() = 0;
    virtual void putdata(type1 dt) = 0;
};
template <class type1>
class Queue :public DataStruct<type1> {
public:
    type1 getdata();
    void putdata(type1 dt);
};
template <class type1>
void Queue<type1>::putdata(type1 dt) {
    DataStruct<type1>* temp = new Queue<type1>;
    temp->data = dt;
    if (this->tail) this->tail->next = temp;
    this->tail = temp;
    temp->next = NULL;
    if (!this->head) this->head = this->tail;
}
template <class type1>
type1 Queue<type1>::getdata() {
    DataStruct<type1>* p;
    type1 i;
    p = this->head;
    i = this->head->data;
    if (!this->head) {
        cout << "Queue is empty!\n";
        exit(1);
    }
    this->head = this->head->next;
    delete p;
    return i;
}
int main() {
    Queue<int> Q;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        Q.putdata(i);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        cout << Q.getdata() << ' ';
    cout << '\n';
    return 0;
} ```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так происходит со всем, что унаследовано из родителя, тип которого зависит от шаблонного параметра, и кроме `this->` можно использовать `Родитель::` или `ЭтотКласс::`.

Подозреваю, это сделано потому, что родителя можно специализировать - чтобы неожиданно не оказалось так, что специализация добавляет туда новую переменную/функцию/тип, совпадающую по имени с глобальной, и то, что раньше было обращением к глобальной, теперь находит унаследованную (или наоборот, в специализации нет какого-то члена, и обращение к нему тепреь находит глобальную сущность с тем же именем).